# Is it possible to add more y-axis labels when making a graph in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to use Illustrator to recreate a line graph I was given. The problem I'm having is that when I use the graph tool in Illustrator, I can't seem to find any option for increasing the number of divisions on the Y-axis.

This is the original:
[image: Line Graph with several Y-labels]

And this is what I have so far in Illustrator (I haven't ungrouped it to start the actual design yet):
[image: Line graph with too few Y-labels]

What I want to do is increase the number of labels on the Y-axis so that they're more similar to the original. I know I can ungroup and manually add the labels, but I'd much rather it be done procedurally to minimize human error.

Comment: The toon is extremely basic, it haw no way of doing this. Either use a external app or draw the labels manually. Personally i would use mathematica for this. But i can understand that most people can not afford it.  Maybe you could use a script?

Comment: yes it is possible I guess with some tricks and hacks. So please if you don't mind please upload the XLS file. I want ti give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes –

1. Click on the graph
2. In the menu bar, navigate to Object \ Graph \ Type...
3. In the window that pops up, select Value Axis in the drop-down menu
4. In the area named Tick Values, select Override Calculated Values
5. Manually set the number of Divisions

Note: Adjusting this setting will reset other customizations you may have made visually to your graph. It's a good idea to get the data portion right before moving on to the design.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd> *click* on the graph and select *Type* (or select the graph, then go **Object → Graph → Type**).

When this window opens, select the drag down menu for graph options and choose *Value axis*.

You can then change the range of the values and the number of divisions.